# The SwiftUI Picker state retrieves the index location and not the tag

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, state

The code below should display a segmented picker with labels 2 to 9, and a text that displays the selected number.  But the number gets the selected  index location (0...7) and not the **tag**. *Is this a bug, or have I misunderstood the tag-thing?*

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var number = 5

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("The number is \(number)")
            Picker(selection: $number, label: Text("The number n")) {
                ForEach( 2..<10 ){ n in
                    Text("\(n)").tag(n)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes `tag` is used for such purpose, but not in this case. For `Picker` selection should be same as id, so here is fixed part

```
Picker(selection: $number, label: Text("The number n")) {
    ForEach( 2..<10, id: \.self ){ n in
        Text("\(n)")
    }
}
```